# Magento 1.8 and Varnish or another FPC

Tags: magento, varnish, magento-1.8

As we all really know, there appears a little problem with Magento 1.8.x and Varnish. Magento team added the support "form_key" for the most the frontend forms and actions. It is really great, everyone should  keep safety first. However it causes a problem with FPC systems as Varnish (great article about this is here http://www.supportdesk.nu/blog/110-magento-1-8-form-keys-impact-on-fpc). Many FPC systems on Magento solves it by putting a placeholder and replace "form_key" during loading a page from cache. It's good for PHP systems that are integrated into Magento , but not for external systems as Varnish. So my question is as follows:

**Is there a good enough solution for using FPC as Varnish and Magento 1.8.x?**

I consider follows

1) prevent using of the "form_key" on frontend, there are many way to do this (e.g: https://bitbucket.org/supportdesk_nl/turpertine-formkey-workaround/src/574ff1851618dc0e76e4274001fbf3efb89c99f6/app/code/community/SupportDesk/CartFormKey/Model/Observer.php?at=master). However this is hack and is not good generaly. Moreover could be a security risk? What do you mean about this?

2) load the "form_key" via AJAX and replace all links and form inputs by JavaScript code. I'm not sure that it is technicaly realizable (e.g: replacing code snippets like onclick="setLocation('....&form_key=XXX');" would be too difficult) and it will causes too many problems and incompatibilities with various extensions.

3) do not use Varnish. Yes it would be a solution, but let's avoid them for now, please.

4) Your suggestions ???

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Which FPC are you trying to use anyway? We use Lesti FPC (with Redis Cache backends, and session backends) with Varnish and it works fine.

I don't know if you've properly read one of the links you posted, but Lesti FPC is already patched via [this commit, 5 months ago](https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc/commit/e3725928fcac1924ed663c33bd4067e99b3e7eb1).

Comment: Thanks for the noticed, I must have been blind. We are using this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/PHOENIX/extension/6322/varnish_cache together with our system and all worked fine until 1.8. Ok, we try this. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello Seth, I have tried to install Lesti FPC and it seems that it works fine, but only as standalone, with Varnish it does not work properly. Could you explain how to set Lesti FPC so that it will handle the form_key for Varnish? Thank you very much.